# Django starts with another view endpoint before finishing the process in the first view endpoint

Tags: javascript, python, json, django, django-rest-framework

What I'm trying to do is create a User object first and then another Team Leader object in which the user attribute is linked to the same User object created. However, what happens is the Create Team Leader is being called BEFORE the Create User is done processing.

Here is the Team Leader Model:

```
class TeamLeader(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)

    firstName = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    lastName = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    username = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    employeeRole = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)
    
    bio = models.TextField(blank=True)
    profileimg = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_images', default='blankprofile.png')
    location = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

I'm sending two post requests to my APIs using fetch in Javascript. Below is my code for the post requests. The first one creates the User object first, then the next one for the Team Leader object.

```
    let userUrl = homeUrl + 'api/createuser/'
    
    fetch(userUrl,{
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Content-type':'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({"username": username,
      "first_name": firstname,
      "last_name": lastname,
      "email": email,
      "password": password1,
      "employeeRole": employeeRole,
      "teamLeader": teamLeader,
    }),
    }
    )


    if (employeeRole == 'Member') {
      var regisUrl = homeUrl + 'api/createMember/';
    } else {
      var regisUrl = homeUrl + 'api/createTeamLeader/';
    }
    
    
    fetch(regisUrl,{  
      method:'POST',
      headers:{
        'Content-type':'application/json',
        'X-CSRFToken':csrftoken,
      },
      body:JSON.stringify({"username": username,
      "first_name": firstname,
      "last_name": lastname,
      "email": email,
      "password": password1,
      "employeeRole": employeeRole,
      "teamLeader": teamLeader,
    }),
    }
    )
```

Here are my api endpoints for the /createuser and /createTeamLeader. I've added print statements just to see which lines of codes are being processed.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def createUser(request):
    serializerUser = UserSerializer(data=request.data)

    print('OUTSIDE SERIALIZER VALID')

    serializerUser.is_valid()
    print(serializerUser.errors)

    if serializerUser.is_valid():

        print('INSIDE SERIALIZER VALID')
        
        username = serializerUser.validated_data['username']
        password = serializerUser.validated_data['password']
        email = serializerUser.validated_data['email']

        user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
        user.first_name = serializerUser.validated_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = serializerUser.validated_data['last_name']
        user.save()

        print('success creating user')
        
    
    return Response(serializerUser.data)

@api_view(['POST'])
def createTeamLeader(request):

    serializer = TeamLeaderSerializer(data=request.data)
    print('CREATING TEAM LEADER')

    if serializer.is_valid():

        username = serializer.validated_data['username']
        email = serializer.validated_data['email']
        employeeRole = serializer.validated_data['employeeRole']

        newAddedUser = User.objects.get(username = username)

        teamleader = TeamLeader.objects.create(user=newAddedUser,firstName=newAddedUser.first_name,lastName = newAddedUser.last_name, email=email,username=username, employeeRole = employeeRole)
        teamleader.save()

    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Here is the output from the terminal. The "Create Team Leader" is called before the User object is done creating.

```
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
July 08, 2023 - 17:31:28
Django version 4.2.2, using settings 'officeIS.settings'
Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Quit the server with CTRL-BREAK.

OUTSIDE SERIALIZER VALID
{}
[08/Jul/2023 17:31:31] CREATING TEAM LEADER"GET /api/allTeamLeaders/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2
INSIDE SERIALIZER VALID

[08/Jul/2023 17:31:31] "GET /api/allUserLogins/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2367
[08/Jul/2023 17:31:31] "GET /api/allUserLogins/ HTTP/1.1" 200 2367
Internal Server Error: /api/createTeamLeader/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py", line 55, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py", line 197, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\decorators\csrf.py", line 56, in wrapper_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\views\generic\base.py", line 104, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\rest_framework\decorators.py", line 50, in handler
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\WORK\Programming Career\officeIS\OfficeIS\core\views.py", line 131, in createTeamLeader
    newAddedUser = User.objects.get(username = username)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 87, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\user\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 637, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
django.contrib.auth.models.User.DoesNotExist: User matching query does not exist.
[08/Jul/2023 17:31:31] "POST /api/createTeamLeader/ HTTP/1.1" 500 106888
success creating user
[08/Jul/2023 17:31:31] "POST /api/createuser/ HTTP/1.1" 200 111
```

I'm really not sure if my interpretation for the output in the terminal is correct. If it is, how do I fix this? Any suggestions on how to design the backend better but still using DRF?

Tried excluding the createTeamLeader post request and just leave the createuser post request, and it works just fine.

Comment: Are you sure you're waiting for the `createUser`'s response on frontend before calling `createTeamLeader` view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is not with Django but with the browser’s fetch API. Actually this isn’t even a problem with any of the above but rather it is because you do not understand how they work.

I’ll explain it in detail so that you can get it up and running again. My explanation will concentrate on the fetch API.

The browser’s fetch api is asynchronous. [See Using the Fetch API on the Mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch)

While you are making two fetch calls at the same time, you cannot predetermine which one will respond first because they are both running asynchronously. This will become a problem if you want one to respond before the other. To solve this you could use async-await to make one wait for the other or you could chain then() calls to one to do something when that one responds. This is a promise based approach. I’ll throw more light on the promise based approach but the article I linked to will give you more knowledge on this topic.

So using the promise based approach I want the “Create Team Leader" endpoint to only get called after the “Create User” endpoint has responded.

```
let userUrl = new URL('api/createuser/', homeUrl)

fetch(userUrl,{
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-type': 'application/json',
    'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    "username": username,
    "first_name": firstname,
    "last_name": lastname,
    "email": email,
    "password": password1,
    "employeeRole": employeeRole,
    "teamLeader": teamLeader,
  }),
})
.then(response => {
  if (employeeRole == 'Member') 
  {
    var regisUrl = new URL('api/createMember/', homeUrl)
  } else 
  {
    var regisUrl = new URL('api/createTeamLeader/', homeUrl)
  }


  fetch(regisUrl,{  
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Content-type': 'application/json',
      'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken,
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "username": username,
      "first_name": firstname,
      "last_name": lastname,
      "email": email,
      "password": password1,
      "employeeRole": employeeRole,
      "teamLeader": teamLeader,
    }),
  })
})
```

You probably want to check the status of response from the first fetch call before making the second fetch call in the then() call. The response.status attribute should have that.

To understand this better, read the documentation on this. Take your time to read the article I linked to earlier.

Have a lovely weekend.